# Apps and OS start takes too long

Tags: ubuntu, boot, application

Sorry if this is a duplicated question. I can't figure it out the answers of this kind of questions.
I'm new to Linux.

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- RAM: 11.7
- PROCESSOR: Intel i7 4790k
- GRAPHICS: R7 260X (using proprietary drivers)

**Start problem:**
When I turn on the PC, after the BIOS screen starts to change from purple to black like 5 times and after that boots to my desktop. (GRUB is not showing and I like it that way.)

**Apps problem:**
Apps like Google Chrome and VMware Workstation take like 10 seconds to open (*the first time*. If I close and re-open the app, takes less than a second to open.). and after that works perfect. But how can I optimize that first opening?

Comment: Consider buying some SSD disk for your system.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you start an application (or otherwise read from disk into memory), the data from disk are cached into free RAM (called 'buffers' in the output of `free`).  If the same data need to be read a successive time before the cache is discarded or used for other data, they are read from RAM which is naturally faster than being read from disk.  The only reasonable way to speed up the first startup time is to get a faster storage medium.